# How to make this animation on Android?

Tags: android, material-design

http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-Vv4SxVSI2DY/VEqQxAf3PWI/AAAAAAAAA7c/mfq7XBrIGgo/s1600/activity_transitions%2B(1).gif

I was reading about Material Design and I fall in love with this transition. Its named "Activity + Fragment Transitions" on the post.
Has anyone a tutorial or a name so I can search more precise?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](https://github.com/malmstein/MaterialAnimations) implementation on Activity transitions which i am using!